# How do you put space between an image and colored background

Tags: image, wordpress, css

I am trying to put basically a border around an image of just white space then a colored background within the block element and caption for the image.  Here is the page I'm trying to do this to http://www.metnews.org/news/aurora-remembers-holmes-victims/

thanks.

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure what you have tried. But why not just add a white border to it's container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your writing your border css wrong, look at tags in article.post .wp-caption img on line 1012 of style.css:

```
 border: 5px #FFF;
```

Should probably read:

```
 border: 5px solid #FFF;
```

When I add that in, the border shows around the images.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are constructed like

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

, you can style a white background around the image like this:

```
.container {
    background-color: red;
}

.container img {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px /* to expose the white background */
    background-color: white;
}
```